# SPOJ CCHESS ( Costly Chess )

Tags: algorithm

I am doing a problem CCHESS, here is the link ( http://www.spoj.pl/problems/CCHESS/ )  to the problem.

The question is  as follows:

In the country of Rome, Chess is a royal game. For evey move the players had to give some bucks to the Emperor Jurg. The LGMs or Little Green Men, are very good player of chess. But as the chess is a expensive game, thats why it is royal, they asked you to help them find the minimum bucks which they had to pay for moving their Knight from one position to another. Any number of steps can be used to reach the destination.

Constraints:

The chess has a dimension of 8X8, and the index of left bottom cell (0, 0).

Knight move only in a standard way, i.e. 2 row and 1 col or 1 row and 2 col.

If in a step Knight move from (a, b) to (c, d), then LGM had to pay a*c + b*d bucks to Emperor Jurg.

```
0 ≤ a, b, c, d ≤ 7
```

Input

There are 100-150 test cases. Each test case is composed of four space separeated integers.The first two numbers, a, b, are the starting position of the Knight and the next two, c, d, are the destination of the Knight. Read upto End Of File.
Output

For each test case, print the minimum amount of bucks they had to pay in separate line. If its impossible to reach the destination then print -1.

Example

Input:

```
2 5 5 2
4 7 3 2
1 2 3 4
```

Output:

42
78
18

Explanation for test case #1:
2 5 5 2

For moving Knight from 
    (2, 5) to (5, 2)

```
in minimum cost,  one of the path is 

(2, 5) -> (3, 3) ->(5, 2)
```

Bucks paid:

```
(2, 5)              =  0
(2, 5) -> (3, 3) =  0 + (2*3 + 5*3) = 21
(3, 3) -> (5, 2) = 21 + (3*5 + 3*2) = 42
```

To infinity and beyond...

I have done this problem using brute force, i.e. checking recursively all the possible paths but i think i am missing somewhere to find a direct approach, because numerous submissions are of 0.00 where as my recursive approach got accepted in 0.3s . 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the question itself here, so that your question is still useful even if the link ever dies.

Comment: You could try posting in the spoj forums itself. Or check : [http://www.spoj.pl/forum/search.php?keywords=CCHess](http://www.spoj.pl/forum/search.php?keywords=CCHess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Construct a graph G=(V,E) where 
V is the set of coordinates in the grid {v=(x,y)} 
E is the set of edges between vertices
Assign weights on the edges where weight is (v1.x * v2.x + v1.y*v2.y) 
Use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path (1 source - 1 destination)
source = (a,b) and destination = (c,d)
If there is no path report -1.

The number of vertices are limited to (8*8) = 64
The number of edges are limited to 64 * (8) = 512 
as the knight can move to at most 8 other coordinates from one place.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try A* algorithm, with heuristic = manhattan_distance/3 .

Comment: i am unaware of A* algorithm, but after your post i read it from several resources but i am confused about heuristics. Can you explain a bit more.