# Confusion regarding the algorithm to be applied for CCHESS

Tags: algorithm

I am aware of the fact that I have to apply Dijkstra's algorithm to get an answer.The entire algorithm is explained in depth in one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419505/spoj-cchess-costly-chess) .
However why do we need to apply Dijkstra's algorithm to this problem.According to my knowledge Dijkstra will find the shortest distance path.

But the problem setter has clearly asked for minimum cost path.Considering this should'nt we apply Prim's algorithm to the question and find the MST for the entire chess board.

[Here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CCHESS/)  is the link to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's algorithm is indeed for finding the shortest distance path.  However, note that "distance" does not have to mean distance measured in the normal way (i.e. with a ruler).

In fact Dijkstra's algorithm will also work for finding the shortest cost path in any network (providing that all the costs are greater than or equal to zero).  All you need to do is to define the distance between any two nodes to be equal to the cost of the corresponding edge.

So, in this problem, when they search for the shortest path, they are defining distance in terms of the cost function defined in the problem.

Comment: Can you please explain the line "In fact Dijkstra's algorithm will also work for finding the shortest cost path in any network (providing that all the costs are greater than or equal to zero)".  According to me the shortest path and minimum cost path are never the same.

Comment: If we define the "distance" between two nodes to be the cost of taking that edge, then the "distance" for a path is just another way of saying the cost of the path.  In other words, we are using "distance" as a synonym for cost.